# Send HTML form via axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

In my vue app I have a regular `<form>` when I hit submit it sends the right data but it doesn't set the authentication headers on the request. I have axios configured to attach these headers on every request so I need to send the data via axios.

From the axios docs I know I can post data like this

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
```

and I also know I can run a custom function on a form post by adding `@submit.prevent="handleSubmit` to the `<form>` tag.

What I can't work out is how to get all the values from the form inputs and send it via axios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `handleSubmit` function, you can use the FormData class like:

```
handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let formData = new FormData(event.target)
    axios.post('/user', formData).then(response => ...).catch(error => ...)
}
```